# How to move a specific person in call to another call [Discord.js]

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a command that moves a person in one discord call to another on my server with an @mention then the channel name, I've been trying for hours now and I still have no idea on how to do it

```js
const { Command } = require('discord.js-commando');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = class MoveCommand extends Command {
 constructor(client) {
  super(client, {
   name: 'move',
   aliases: ['m'],
   memberName: 'move',
   group: 'guild',
   description: 'Use to move other people in call',
   guildOnly: true,
   userPermissions: ['MANAGE_CHANNELS', 'MOVE_MEMBERS'],
   clientPermissions: ['MANAGE_CHANNELS', 'MOVE_MEMBERS'],
   args: [
    {
     key: 'usersToMove',
     prompt:
      'Please mention the user you want to move with @ or provide his/her ID.',
     type: 'string',
    },
    {
     key: 'Channel',
     prompt: 'Please mention the Channel you wish to move the user to.',
     type: 'string',
    },
   ],
  });
 }

 run(message, { usersToMove, Channel }) {
  const user =
   message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.fetch(usersToMove);
  if ((user, Channel == undefined))
   return message.channel.send('Please try again with a valid user');
  return message.channel.send('Please try again with a valid Channel');
  user.then(() => mem.voice.setChannel(message.member.voice.channel));
  message.channel.send(':right_facing_fist: ' + member).catch((e) => {
   message.say(
    'Something went wrong when trying to move this user, I probably do not have the permission to move this user or some shit'
   );
   return console.error(e);
  });
 }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't write down what the actual current result is of your code but I'll take a wild guess and say your code always returns the text 'Please try again with a valid channel'.

The reason for my guess is that you have a return statement right after your if statement, which will therefore always be fired (unless your if statement returns true, in which case it will still return out of your code but with a different message).

Take a look at the code below and give it a try. I've added comments to explain what everything does:

```js
run(message, { usersToMove, Channel }) {
  // Get the mentioned user
  const user = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.fetch(usersToMove);
  
  // Check if the user is valid
  if (!user) return message.channel.send('Please try again with a valid user');
  
  // Check if the channel is valid
  if (!Channel) return message.channel.send('Please try again with a valid Channel');
  
  // If we reach this point, we know we have a valid user AND a valid Channel
  
  // Move the mentioned user to the mentioned Channel
  user.voice.setChannel(Channel)
    // If the moving was successful, send a success message
    .then(() => {
      message.channel.send(`:right_facing_fist: ${user}`);
    })
    // If the moving was unsuccessful, send a message with the error
    .catch((error) => {
      message.channel.send(`Something went wrong with moving the user. Here's the error: ${error}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried it out just now but the thing is I have to copy the ID of the channel instead of just typing out the Channel name, is there a way so I can type the name of the channel instead of copying the ID?

Comment: You can find a channel by name by simply doing `const channelByName = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === <The name the user has given in the message>);`.

Comment: I haven't even tried this but I'm going to thank you anyways for you are the angel to all my problems I love you dude thank you so much